# CUDA does not work on Visual Studio 2013 - toolkits 4.2, 5.5 and 6

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, cuda, visual-studio-2013

I understand that Cuda 6 does not work with Visual Studio 2013. But shouldn't Cuda 5.5. or Cuda 4.2 work with Visual Studio 2013?

I have Cuda 4.2, 5.5 and 6 installed. If I right click on VS project, and select Build Customizations option, I only see Cuda 6 listed. For Cuda 6, it tells me that I must choose the older v11 toolset, and the other two toolkits are simply non existent.

Is there any way to get Cuda to work on VS 2013?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The supported visual studio versions are listed in the windows getting started guide or toolkit release notes for each CUDA toolkit release.

The CUDA 6 getting started guide is [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-microsoft-windows/index.html#abstract).

The only toolkit that officially has support for VS 2013 at this time is [CUDA 6.5RC available for download](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit) to registered developers.

Comment: Do you think it is safe to install Cuda 6.5 RC on my development machine to try it out?

Comment: I use it.  CUDA 6.5 will be in a Production status soon, if you want to wait for it.